# When to compile apps that use a changed runtime package

Tags: delphi, runtime-packages

I'm using Delphi XE2.  I have a large project that has an application (EXE) that uses runtime packages, a `Core.bpl` custom package (used by the EXE) and several other custom `Plugin.bpl` packages that also use the `Core.bpl` package (as a runtime package).

I have noticed that I can make minor changes to the `Core.bpl` without recompiling the EXE or custom `Plugin.bpl` packages.  But more significant changes (adding a lot of code or removing a lot of code from an existing method, or adding new methods) causes problems.  Sometimes there are inconsistent access violations, sometimes there are errors about missing entry points in the `Core.bpl` package, etc.

I want to minimize the number of files that are compiled so that our users have fewer files to update with each release.  However, I don't want them to see errors like I sometimes see.

Should I recompile all the modules and the EXE that uses `Core.bpl` each time it changes, or are there some general rules to follow so that everything only gets compiled for certain types of changes to the `Core.bpl`?

Comment: If you change the interface then you must recompile all dependend parts

Comment: @SirRufo make it an answer ..

Comment: @SirRufo - Is that to say, if you add, change or remove methods or properties, then you must recompile everything, but if you simply change the code of an existing method without changing its parameters, then nothing needs to be recompiled?

Comment: Yes, thats the point :o)

Comment: @SirRufo - Thanks, if you make it an answer, I'll mark it correct...

Comment: Some additional informations [bpl_vs_dll](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/bpl_vs_dll.htm)

Comment: Thanks @bummi for the additional info.

Comment: Modifying private members also changes the interface. Basically any changes made above the `implementation` line require a rebuild of all dependent code.

Comment: @afrazier - I like they way you worded your comment.  That's an easier way of looking at it -- especially since the word `interface` has multiple meanings.  You should type it as an answer so that people can upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you change the [**interface section**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Programs_and_Units#The_Interface_Section) of a unit in a BPL you have to recompile the depended parts (EXE or other BPL).

Comment: That is to say, anything above the `implementation` line.

Comment: @JamesL. The **interface section** starts at the word **interface** and ends just before the word **implementation**

Comment: Yes - I realize that.  When I first read the word `interface` in your comment above, I thought you were talking about interfaces in the programming sense of the word.  But then realized you meant as it pertains to a Delphi unit.